Number of vertices of product of polytopes
If one takes the product of a polytope $P_1$ with another polytope $P_2$, where $P_1$ has $n$ vertices and $P_2$ has $m$ vertices, will the product of the two polytopes have $mn$ vertices?
It is not assumed that the polytopes have the same dimension.

By "product", do you mean the Cartesian product? I.e., if $P_1$ and $P_2$ are in $\Bbb R^m$ and $\Bbb R^m$ respectively, then their product would be in $\Bbb R^m \times \Bbb R^n \equiv \Bbb R^{m+n}$? If so, then the answer is yes. The products will still be vertices.

First of all you ought become aware that there are quite a few different products which can be defined for polytopes, cf. e.g. 1, 2:
The pyramid product, when restricted to convex polytopal factors, simply is described as putting each factor into mutually affine shifted orthogonal subspaces and then takes thereof the hull. The total dimension of the outcome thus clearly is the sum of the dimensions of the factors plus one. Esp. the pyramid itself will be a prominent member here, then being the pyramid product of the base (facet) and its tip (vertex). - Obviously here the vertex count of the outcome would be the sum of the vertex counts of its factors.
The tegum product (also known as join product or direct sum), when restricted to convex polytopal factors, simply is described as putting each factor into mutually (non-affine, i.e. non-shifted) orthogonal subspaces and then takes thereof the hull. The total dimension of the outcome thus clearly is the sum of the dimensions of the factors. Esp. the general cross-polytope (or hyper-octahedron) is a prominent member here, then being nothing but the tegum product of n (orthogonal) line segments, which thus become thereby its diagonals. - Again the vertex count of the outcome of this product would be the sum of the vertex counts of its factors.
The total dimension of the prism product also is sum of the dimensions of the factors. In fact it takes a copy of the first factor (considered to stretch through the first few according dimensions) at the vertex positions of the other factor (then considered to stretch through the remaining few dimension, i.e. within respective co-space), then connected as that other factor tells. Those thus clearly are the duoprisms of the respective factors. If one factor happens to be a single line segment, then that outcome happens to be a normal prism, i.e. putting the other factor as a base once at the bottom and once at the top. - Here you would be right indeed that the total vertex count happens to be the product of the respective vertex counts of the factors.
It should be mentioned here that the tegum product and the prism product are mutual dual operators: the dual of the prism product of two factor polytopes is nothing but the tegum product of the respective dual factors.
Finally there is a fourth product, the comb product. However that one applies rather to honeycombs (of any dimensionality) as factors instead to finite polytopes. Accordingly the respective vertex counts all would be infinite a priori and therefore the according consideration would become senseless. Here the total dimension happens to be the sum of the dimensions of the factors. But be aware that the dimension of a honeycomb always is its rank minus one (the honeycomb always is just the surface, there is no bulk underneath, as was for the finite polytopes), this dimensional consideration could be restated for the respective ranks that the total rank happens to be the sum of the ranks of the factors minus one!
--- rk
